# Collisions may occur when using Spring @Cacheable and SimpleKeyGenerator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-4, spring-cache, spring-data-redis

When I use `@Cacheable` and call different method with same parameter,  it generated a same key.
`SimpleKeyGenerator` generated key without cache names.

I use spring-boot 1.3.2 with spring 4.2.4.

Here is a sample:

```
@Component
public static class CacheableTestClass {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "test-cacheproxy-echo1")
    public String echo1(String text) {
        return text;
    }

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "test-cacheproxy-echo2")
    public String echo2(String text) {
        return "Another " + text;
    }
}
```

And run a test:

```
assertEquals("OK", cacheableTestClass.echo1("OK"));
assertEquals("Another OK", cacheableTestClass.echo2("OK")); // Failure: expected 'Another OK', actual 'OK'.
```

So, is there a way to resolve this issue?
Thanks a lot.

**Update**

Here is my `CacheManager` configuration.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "cacheRedisTemplate")
public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> cacheRedisTemplate(
        RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory)
        throws UnknownHostException {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(template.getKeySerializer());
    return template;
}

@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(@Qualifier("cacheRedisTemplate")  RedisTemplate<Object, Object> cacheRedisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(cacheRedisTemplate);
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(
            redisCacheProperties().getDefaultExpiration());
    cacheManager.setExpires(redisCacheProperties().getExpires());
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Comment: Post your configuration for the CacheManager. From your code snippets the keys should not collide as you are using different cache names

Comment: @ekemchitsiga Update my configuration for the `CacheManager`.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `SimpleKeyGenerator` but this is a redis-specific issue that does not use the name of the cache as a discriminant for the key it uses to store the value.

You need to invoke `setUsePrefix(true)` on your `RedisCacheManager`. This is what Spring Boot does when it auto-configures the cache manager for you. Note that it should have been the default and we're discussing how we can improve the out-of-the-box experience in a future release

Comment: If i understand correctly I definitely agree that this should be the default mode. Futhermore, I do not understand then what is the point of `cacheNames` if the `RedisCacheManager` ignores them

Comment: It does ignore them by default and that was a mistake.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that and got errors because of collisions. Now i'm setting `<property name="usePrefix" value="true"/>` when I created `RedisCacheManager` ( yeah, I'm still use xml :)

Comment: @StephaneNicoll Do we have any progress for this problem?

Comment: They rewrote the Redis cache manager and I believe it's fixed. You can ask on the #spring-data gitter channel.